# MySQL INNER JOIN 3 tables and also DELETE using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, sql-delete

I'm really struggling with this task so any help or guidance will be very much appreciated.

The tables:

```
            module_uploads
            +--------------------------+
            | upload_id | upload_name  | 
            +--------------------------+
            |   1006    | 12.png       |
            |   1007    | 18.png       |
            +--------------------------+

            module_timelimit
            +------------------------------------------------+
            | upload_id | email        | expires             |
            +------------------------------------------------+
            |   1006    | me@me.com    | 2014-05-22 16:34:54 |
            |   1007    | me12@me.com  | 2015-05-20 20:34:54 |
            +------------------------------------------------+

            module_fieldvals
            -----------------------------------------+
            | upload_id | fld_id  | value            |
            -----------------------------------------+
            |   1006    | 2       | me@me.com        |
            |   1006    | 0       | mcdda8fbr        |
            |   1007    | 0       | mcdda8fbr        |
            |   1007    | 2       | me12@me.com      |
            -----------------------------------------+
```

Ok so I want to join the 3 tables based upon the upload_id where the expiry date has passed, delete the files, send an email and then delete all the data. I have 2 problems:

- I can only seem to join the tables using fld_id = 2 and group them by expiry date. It would be nice to be able to delete data that has fld_id = 2 and fld_id = 0, but I seemed to get duplicate emails being sent because the while loop was iterating 4 times instead of just 2.
- I can't figure out how to then delete the data
- Is there a way to do it using just one SQL query?

Here is my code so far:

```
            $database       = cmsms()->getDb();
            $now            = $database->DbTimeStamp(time());
            $query          = "
                            SELECT 
                                module_uploads.upload_id,
                                module_uploads.upload_name,
                                module_fieldvals.upload_id,
                                module_fieldvals.fld_id,
                                module_fieldvals.value,
                                module_timelimit.upload_id,
                                module_timelimit.email,
                                module_timelimit.expires
                            FROM
                                module_timelimit
                            INNER JOIN module_uploads
                                ON module_timelimit.upload_id = module_uploads.upload_id
                            INNER JOIN module_fieldvals
                                ON module_timelimit.upload_id = module_fieldvals.upload_id
                            WHERE module_timelimit.expires < $now AND module_fieldvals.fld_id = 2
                            GROUP BY module_timelimit.expires";

            $result         = mysql_query($query);

            // Delete the rows
            $query_deletion = "
                            DELETE cms_module_uploads_timelimit, cms_module_uploads, cms_module_uploads_fieldvals
                            FROM
                                cms_module_uploads_timelimit
                            INNER JOIN cms_module_uploads
                                ON cms_module_uploads_timelimit.upload_id = cms_module_uploads.upload_id
                            INNER JOIN cms_module_uploads_fieldvals
                                ON cms_module_uploads_timelimit.upload_id = cms_module_uploads_fieldvals.upload_id
                            WHERE cms_module_uploads_timelimit.expires < $now AND cms_module_uploads_fieldvals.fld_id = 2
                            GROUP BY cms_module_uploads_timelimit.expires";

            $delete_result  = mysql_query($query_deletion);             

            // Check if any queries failed              
            if(!$result || !$delete_result) {
                if (!$result) exit("Error - The selection query did not succeed");
                if (!$delete_result) exit("Error - The deletion query did not succeed");
            } else {

                // set up the settings for FTP to delete file
                $ftp_server = 'xxxxxxx';
                $ftpuser = 'xxxxxx';
                $ftppass = 'xxxxxx';

                // set up basic connection
                $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

                // login with username and password
                $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpuser, $ftppass);

                if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {

                    echo "Error could not connect to FTP";

                } else {

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $upload_id = $row['upload_id'];
                        $file = $row['upload_name'];
                        $email = $row['value'];

                        // Check if file and email exists
                        if(isset($file) && isset($email) ) {

                            $file = '/uploads/adverts/'.$file;

                            // Delete file
                            if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $file)) {
                                echo "$file deleted successfully\n";
                            } else {
                                echo "could not delete $file\n";
                            }

                            // Send email using CMSMS GCB
                            $cmsmailer->Send(); 
                        }
                    }
                }

                // close the connection
                ftp_close($conn_id);
            }
```

Comment: Could you help me write it? I have no idea if what I am doing is correct!

Comment: It would be nice if 'GROUP BY' was somehow unavailable to new users.

Comment: ?? Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your table names because they're different in your `SELECT` and `DELETE`.

While there is more than one format to delete from multiple tables, your main issue is that you must drop the `GROUP BY` clause from the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE
FROM cms_module_uploads_timelimit, cms_module_uploads, cms_module_uploads_fieldvals
USING cms_module_uploads_timelimit
INNER JOIN cms_module_uploads
  ON cms_module_uploads_timelimit.upload_id = cms_module_uploads.upload_id
INNER JOIN cms_module_uploads_fieldvals
  ON cms_module_uploads_timelimit.upload_id = cms_module_uploads_fieldvals.upload_id
WHERE cms_module_uploads_timelimit.expires < $now
  AND cms_module_uploads_fieldvals.fld_id = 2
```

Comment: Yes sorry I was meant to edit those. They should be the same as the table names in the SELECT. Sorry. I'll give your suggestion a try thank you.

Comment: While this is fine, the original DELETE / JOIN syntax was also fine - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html . The OP specified the tables to delete the records from immediatly after the DELETE keyword, using FROM / INNER JOIN just to link the tables to identify the records.

Comment: That worked thank you very much :-) Do you have any ideas if I can delete the rows with fld_id = 0 at the same time too?